# How can i add animation to the splash screen?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-animation

I don't know why but animations for splash screen isn't working at all.
I guess my codes are correct!..
All I want is to perform the animation on the splash screen content.

```
public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity {
    Animation topAnim, bottomAnim;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;

    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT=4000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        topAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.top_animation);
        bottomAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.bottom_animation);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        imageView.startAnimation(topAnim);
        textView.startAnimation(bottomAnim);

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent homeIntent =new Intent(Welcome.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
                finish();
            }
        },SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

    }
}
```

**These are the bottom and top animations .xml files respectively**

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:duration="1500" />

<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.1"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="1500" />
```

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="-50%"
    android:duration="2000" />

<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.1"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="1500" />
```

Comment: I had tried using setAnimation instead of startAnimation but still it is the same,
the splashscreen do works but not the animation

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
getWindow().setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
```

With

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
```

And remove `setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);` from above

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the followimg line:

setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

above this line: new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

And it would work fine.